# event.preventDefault() not working under pagebeforeshow

Tags: jquery, mobile

In my app I have a button declared using the anchor link

```
<a href="#page-newApp" id="newBttnImg" data-role="button" class="customIcon" data-theme="b" data-transition="pop"><font size="5">New Application</font></a>
```

On click of this button it is supposed to load page with id page-newApp which is the id of the default page that the button is supposed to navigate to.

But, I want to perform a check on a certain key in localStorage object and if the key doesn't exist, I want it to navigate to a different page.

I already have some code implemented under pagebeforeshow event of page-newApp. I have tried to check for the required condition inside this event. That navigates me to the different page that I want to but briefly shows the page-newApp page.

I have tried using event.preventDefault inside pagebeforeshow event but that doesn't seem to work.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#page-newApp', function(event, data){

if(localStorage.getItem('agentSettings') == null || localstorage.getItem('agentSettings') == undefined){

    event.preventDefault();
    $.mobile.changePage("#page-agent-profile");
    return false;
}
currentPage = 0;

$('#mainNavigation a').live('click', function () {
    return false;
});
$('#mainNavigation a').live('touchstart', function () {
    return false;
});

//some more code here

goToPage();
```

});

Comment: page-newApp is the id of the default page that the button is supposed to navigate to

Comment: could you  post the your relevant js code, where u have defined `pagebeforeshow`module

Comment: @Sergey It was there in question but the OP has not used the code segment, so only "New Application" was rendered with font 5. :)

Comment: @Aditya Thanks for the editing. As I said I am quite new here.

Comment: @Sergey I have put the required JS code.

Comment: I have also tried putting the localstorage check inside the pagebeforecreate and pagebeforeload events for the page but with no luck.